# Convert a List to a Map of unique values from the List with key as a single element

Tags: java, list, hashmap, set, java-stream

I have a list as below -

```
List<List<String>> originalList = 
    List.of(List.of("C1", "C2", "C3"), List.of("C2", "C3", "C1"));
```

I am collecting unique elements across lists and arrived at -

```
Set<String> uniqueValues = originalList.stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Now I'm trying to create a map which will look like below -

```
{C3=[C1, C2], C1=[C3, C2], C2=[C3, C1]}
```

I have the below  snippet -

```
Map<String, Set<String>> mymap = uniqueValues
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                    value -> uniqueValues, (left, right) -> {
                        left.removeAll(right);
                        return left;
                    }));
```

which is giving me -

```
{C3=[C3, C1, C2], C1=[C3, C1, C2], C2=[C3, C1, C2]}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You could just make another pass over the map to remove the key from the map: `mymap.forEach((k, v) -> v.remove(k))`

Comment: Is it possible to do in the same iteration without an additional looping. Also after i execute `mymap.forEach((k, v) -> v.remove(k))` the above i get the below  - {C3=[], C1=[], C2=[]}

Comment: Ah. Your first problem is that every value in the map is *the same* Set: altering one alters them all.

Comment: Gotcha, I changed a bit and i am able to get desired result -

`Map<String, Set<String>> mymap = uniqueValues
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                        value -> new HashSet<>(uniqueValues)));

        mymap.forEach((k, v) -> v.remove(k));`

Comment: Basically creating new HashSet for every subset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your goal is to create a map where each entry represents a combination generated based on a set `uniqueValues`.

And obviously each combination is distinct, which means it requires its own `Set`.  I.e. instead of providing the `uniqueValues` as a *value* for every *key*, you need to generate a new `HashSet` based on the `uniqueValues` and remove the current *key* from it.

Another mistake is that you don't need a flavor of `toMap()` collector that expects three arguments because `mergeFunction` (the third argument) is meant to resolve duplicates, but there would be no duplicates in the stream since its source is a `Set`.

To achieve this we need a version of [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) that expects only a `keyMapper` (*a function which produces a key from a stream element*) and `valueMapper` (*a function responsible for generating a value from a stream element*).

That's how it can be done:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> myMap = uniqueValues
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        str -> {
            Set<String> value = new HashSet<>(uniqueValues);
            value.remove(str);
            return value;
        }
    ));

System.out.println(myMap);
```

*Output:*

```
{C3=[C1, C2], C1=[C3, C2], C2=[C3, C1]}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was missing. I failed to create a new HashSet for every subset and that was removing all the entries from the subset.